# android copy StringBuffer

Tags: java, android

I have declared two string buffers like,

```
private StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(1024);
private StringBuffer bufRetro = new StringBuffer(1024);
```

on following code, before bufRetro = buf, buf has proper filled value. However, after copy it, both have no content. How to set one stringBuffer from another one? Thank you.

```
if(this.v_Id){

    buf.append(ch, start, length);

    if (bufType.equals(bufOld)){

        buf = bufRetro.append(buf);

    }

    myParsedXMLDataSet.setId(buf.toString());

    bufOld = bufType;

    bufRetro.delete(0, bufRetro.length());
    bufRetro = buf;

    Log.d("id", buf.toString());

    buf.delete(0, buf.length());
```

Comment: You're performing *lots* of operations here - and assigning each variable to the other. Please create a *short but complete* example which *only* shows the bit which is confusing you.

Comment: I'm also having trouble following this code.... From initial inspection it looks as though you are losing the reference to the 'buf' StringBuffer in the line "buf = bufRetro.append(buf);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***How to set one stringBuffer from another one?***

How about

```
bufRetro.setLength(0);   // copy content from buf to bufRetro
bufRetro.append(buf);

buf.setLength(0);        // if you want to clear the original one.
```